# Can I put a progress bar in dockerfile COPY?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have created a dockerfile for my nodejs project
I am first copying the code files of current directory to docker image

```
COPY ./ ./
```

I wonder, is there any option (or some other way), using which I can see the progress of copy in terminal ?
something like ...

```
50% completed ...
```

It will be more helpful if I can do the same when using docker-compose !

Comment: Do you have a more specific example where this `COPY` takes substantial time?  IME the `COPY` statement itself is quite fast, but the initial step of sending a large build context to Docker can be slow; also that an image that's large enough that you're worried about the time `COPY` takes will have a number of other practical problems and you should look for ways to reduce this data volume.

Comment: You are right ! But, during the testing phase. I avoid commands like `npm install` on docker (because sometimes I face permission issues), therefore, during the testing I also copy the node_modules. In that case, `COPY` takes a noticeable time. @DavidMaze

Comment: Generally you should include `node_modules` in a `.dockerignore` file, so `COPY` (and the build context) excludes it.  `RUN npm ci` in the Dockerfile to install the packages listed in `package.json` and `package-lock.json`.

Comment: agree with @DavidMaze. see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/#creating-a-dockerfile - the documentation also suggests excluding `node_modules` and installing packages listed in `package.json` and `package-lock.json`

Comment: Yes, I am aware about the usage of .dockerignore and the best practises. But, my question is completely different here. I am simply trying to add a progress bar (or something similar), is that technically possible ? It is not bad thing to show the progress bar even if the process takes less time, is it ?

Comment: Agree with @KevalBhogayata here, the original question was how one might add a progress bar to the docker COPY command, not "best practices for .dockerignore in node applications".